# How can I mock asyncpg executemany and fetch methods using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-mock, asyncpg

I am using pytest and asyncpg to load and save items to the database. How do I test the 2 functions below?

```
import asyncpg
config = {host: "localhost", port: 5432, database: "postgres"}


async def read_data():
    async with asyncpg.create_pool(**config) as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            feeds = await conn.fetch(
                "select feed_id, url, etag, last_modified from feeds WHERE enabled=TRUE"
            )
            return feeds


async def write_data(items):
    async with asyncpg.create_pool(**config) as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            query = '''
                INSERT INTO
                    feed_items (feed_item_id, pubdate, link, guid, title, summary, content, author, feed_id) 
                VALUES
                    (
                        $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9
                    )
                    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
            '''
            await conn.executemany(query, items)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the unit test, even if it is not yet doing what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H i have tried reading the documentation , nothing is mentioned about pytest https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/search.html?q=pytest&check_keywords=yes&area=default# I have tried searching github issues https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues?q=pytest no example anywhere, also tried searching pytest issues https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues?q=asyncpg+

Comment: @J_H what I can do is make a function currently like def test_connection_pool(): being new to python and pytest i have no idea what to write inside in order to stub or mock the db

Comment: When asking this question or any question on SO, please offer an MRE to help us help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your question as stated is "How can I test ..." That means exercise the target function and verify it returns correct answer without crashing. None of that is especially dependent on pytest, which just executes the test code. Your comment suggests an entirely separate question, "How can I mock...", which _is_ pytest specific. Mocking an INSERT could be write-to-file or merely a no-op `return`. Mocking the SELECT could be read-from-file or merely returning constant list.

Comment: This _could_ be a great question. In e.g. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/70 I see mention of many pytest-specific async features that you might plausibly be grappling with. The question, and any correct answer(s) it elicits, could have much value for future engineers grappling with similar testing issues. But if you won't reveal your current attempts at writing a unit test, we are rather hampered in addressing the specifics.

Comment: are you trying to mock the database access or actually hit a database when testing? mocking these database calls wouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: hitting the actual database would mean i simply create a test database right? i dont think that would be an issue if true. So the question is how would I mock them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can mock the database calls, however there isn't much to test when doing that. Your functions simply read/write some data, there isn't much logic or conditionals to verify. My recommendation would be to spin up a Postgres instance in a Docker container alongside your tests and test by hitting that.

With that being said, below you can find how to mock your database calls and test some basic functionality. You will need to install `pytest-asyncio` to get this to work.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest
import pytest_asyncio

from src.get_events import read_data, write_data


# fixture which mocks database behavior
# take note that you have to mock __aenter__ on the calls as you are
# using with statements in your code
@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def db_conn():
    with patch("src.get_events.asyncpg") as mock_pool:
        mock_pool.configure_mock(
            **{
                "create_pool.return_value.__aenter__.return_value": mock_pool,
                "acquire.return_value.__aenter__.return_value": mock_pool
            }
        )

        yield mock_pool


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_read_data(db_conn):
    expected = [1, 2, 3]
    expected_query = "select feed_id, url, etag, last_modified from feeds WHERE enabled=TRUE"

    async def fetch():
        return expected
    
    # async function calls need to return an awaitable
    db_conn.fetch.return_value = fetch()

    feeds = await read_data()
    
    assert feeds == expected
    # assert function was called with the query we expect
    db_conn.fetch.assert_called_once_with(expected_query)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_write_data(db_conn):
    async def sink(*args, **kwargs):
        return

    items = [3, 4]
    db_conn.executemany.return_value = sink()
    await write_data(items)

    db_conn.executemany.assert_called_once()
    kall = db_conn.executemany.call_args
    # confirm that the items passed in to the function are the same ones
    # being sent to the database
    assert items in kall.args
```

---

```
=============================================================== test session starts ===============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: **
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                 

tests/test_script.py::test_read_data PASSED
tests/test_script.py::test_write_data PASSED

================================================================ 2 passed in 0.03s ================================================================
```