# How to write an integration test for asyncpg using TempCluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, asyncpg

I want to write tests for asyncpg code to get a 100% coverage. I could mock it which was covered in a different question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72742003/how-can-i-mock-asyncpg-executemany-and-fetch-methods-using-pytest) or The author of asyncpg states that [there is a another method using TempCluster](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/589#issuecomment-734507729)

I could not find anything in asyncpg documentation on how to use this TempCluter. Could some kindly share a sample of how to test asyncpg with TempCluster

Answer (score 0):

(I similarly wanted to mock asyncio, and followed recommendation in #589. And actually perhaps that's more reliable test as it also can somewhat test correctness of my SQL.

I also tried to run cluster.start(port="dynamic") as a thread, but it just changed message from:
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

to:
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Although after investigating it more I think it actually might be similar problem but this time in TestClient in FastAPI and the nest_asyncio was hiding it, so I think it solves the problem.

But since the crux of my issue is that I'm already in an event loop when running the cluster, I'm wondering if maybe less hacky solution would be actually detecting that and maybe return a future with when connection is ready, or having an alternative start() method that's async?)
there is a discussion on this at https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/789